# is it possible to make some vps with a single share ip using linux?

Tags: linux, ip, vps

I want to make a vps center to provide vps for users.I want to assign ip to vps BUT I wonder is it possible for vps centres to assign share ip to all vps? like share hosting

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Perhaps you are not a native English speaker? Can you provide more details on what you are trying to do, so that we might better understand your question?

Comment: Sounds like you need a load balancer, maybe.

Comment: Sounds like you need a sysadmin, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NATting & port forwarding would be as close as it can get; you wouldn't be able to e.g. have a web-server on 3 VPS' on the default http port if they're natted.

As for the "internal IP": like posters in the comment section I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to make a vps center to provide vps for users.I want to assign ip to vps BUT I wonder is it possible for vps centres to assign share ip to all vps? like share hosting